# Use the rest syntax to declare this function's arguments in Dojo

Tags: sonarqube, dojo

The SonarQube report suggests to Use the rest syntax to declare this function's arguments

this.inherited(arguments);

Based on this suggestion , I tried changing the code as below, but this do not seem to work.Error on console "declare.js:99 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom' of undefined"

this.inherited(...arguments);

Please suggest how can I resolve issue in SonarQube

Comment: Also tried this.inherited(...args). Error on console : 
Uncaught ReferenceError: args is not defined

Comment: The underlying problem is , I am unable to pass callee in this.inherited(...arguments);

Comment: Please post (part of) your code so we can see the context.

Answer (score 0):

declare the function where the problem is something like function(...args) and call the needed function like this this.inherited(args)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).